# For loop vs lapply, can't replicate the for loop

Tags: r

I'm not very used to `lapply` and the whole `apply` family. I can make my loop work in a `for` loop but I am unable to when trying to shift to `lapply`.

What can be wrong?

My code

Purpose: Trying to delete all list items that do not contain any rows.

```
for(i in 1:length(a.df)) {
# Works great
 if(nrow(a.df[[i]]) == 0) a.df[[i]] <- NULL

}

lapply(seq_along(a.df), function(i) {x  <-  if(nrow(a.df[[i]]) == 0) a.df[[i]]  <- NULL; x }) # returns only NA...
```

Comment: You can iterate directly over the list elements, i.e. `lapply(a.df,function(x) if(nrow(x)==0) NULL else x)`

Comment: Another option (using list subsetting) `a.df[sapply(a.df, nrow) > 0]`.

Comment: Wow. Thank you guys!

Comment: One issue though. For @MaratTalipov solution I get error: x : argument is of length zero, and for Gregors solution I get (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Comment: I got to understand why the subsetting didn't work. It's because I have my list objects in the xts class. Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: How could we possibly know when you have not produced a specific example? It the data situation were as you described it, then Gregor's solution _should_ have succeeded. Your list may have the items nested more deeply than you are aware.

Comment: I think the easiest route would be `Filter(nrow, a.df)`

Comment: I tested my code on `a.df = list(mtcars, dataframe(x = numeric()))`. Works fine.